# Can You Decipher It?

Tags: cipher

Cryptogram Puzzle #1

Message:

> cp pl cq gv ud fl qz nt da bq kl ql ha uv dv ht od qt hd
>
> "np bf qk wa ud lw fd lx cr dl pe bq rm fl
>
> np bf qk wa ud lw fd lx cr dl pe bq mg dV"

Hint 1:

> Why did Odin hang on a tree for three days?

Hint 2

> (related to the answer you get from the first one): It is the oldest of its kind

Hint 3:

> Ciper type: What do adults always tell children when they are playing with other kids in a game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm bad at ciphers, but the clues are probably
1

> Odin hang on a tree to find knowledge, or the runes.

3

> This is most likely the playfair cipher.

Edit:

Thanks to guest for the rest. Hint 2 refers to

> Elder Futhark

and using that as the key gives

> good job, here's your hint for the next upload. Some say the world will end in fire. Some say the world will end in ice.

Comment: Your on the right track, actually. Just piece them together....

Comment: I updated hint two, I shouldve mentioned its related to the first hint

Comment: thecoder16, you can edit my answer into yours if you want and I'll delete mine, I probably wouldn't have bothered looking into those hints

Comment: Well done. Part two has just been uploaded