# Can You Cipher It? #2

Tags: word, cipher

Link to the first cryptogram:
[Can You Decipher It?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60331/can-you-decipher-it)

Cryptogram #2:
kk yn hc im ym nu lr ys rl ua pb at rn lt mk eu ue ui re is zi pw

ii ui bu rr pe dl ss bp rg qk kk zf pw– ew pb oz ev xd ep qb li at ct

Hint #1

> SQUARESQUARESQUARESQUARE

Hint #2 (related to cryptogram #1)

> What that guys name from the last cipher? I forgot

Hint #3 (related to cryptogram #1):

> Where was that from... I seem to be forgetting

Comment: I think the trivia tag should be added to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial(?)

Hint 1 means

> It's a foursquare cipher.

Hint 2 and 3 give us the two keys,

> Robert Frost and "Fire and Ice", the author and poem referenced in the last puzzle.

This gives the answer(?) as

> moving on your next clue this a four lettered answer xmcrees(?) catch phrase from over x– by the way what time is it

So

> McCree's catchphrase is "you know what time it is" and he's from overWATCH, but that's a five letter word?

Oh, but the phrase references

> the answer, high NOON.

Comment: The answer is not formatted correctly yet... its still broken up into pairs...

Comment: added some more...

Comment: lol i'm slow, one step at a time :P

Comment: You got it! Solved

Comment: I'll upload the third one soon... It'll be harder so it migt take time for it to encrypt.