# Can You Cipher It? #3

Tags: word, cipher

Link to cryptogram #1:
[Can You Decipher It?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60331/can-you-decipher-it)

Link to cryptogram #2:
[Can You Cipher It? #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60352/can-you-cipher-it-2)

Cryptogram #3:

U bdayueqp uf iagxp nq tmdpqd.

Zai kag'hq eaxhqp uf, tqdq'e ftq zqjf oxgq.

NxgqQkqeNxgqeQkqeNxgqQkqeBaxkyqdulmfuaz?????

Clue 1

> What time is it?

Clue 2

> Why would I throw food away????

Comment: Just a word of advice: it's best not to post these puzzles *too* close together. Chains of very similar puzzles usually have scores strictly decreasing from one to the next, because some people get bored of them over time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm gonna finish up all of them for today, (there are total of 5) but for the next ones Ill try to space them apart. Is a day apart good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the time was noon, as referenced by the last puzzle,

> We use a caesar cipher with a shift of 12, and get the message "I promised it would be harder. Now you've solved it, here's the next clue. BlueEyesBluesEyesBlueEyesPolymerization"

I guess the answer could be

> Blue Eyes Ultimate Dragon? It's created with 3 Blue Eyes polymerized.